# Blue dot location mapkit

Tags: swift, mapkit

I'm trying to make a maps application using Mapkit. but I can't seem to access the blue dot when i run the app on the simulator. i'm still new to Mapkit and any tips would be really appreciated. here's my code. p.s: i'm coding using Swift 4.2 and Xcode 11

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class mapViewController: UIViewController {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        checkLocationServices()

    }

    func setupLocationManager() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    }

    func centerViewOnUserLocation() {
        if let location = locationManager.location?.coordinate {
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: location, latitudinalMeters: 10000, longitudinalMeters: 10000)
            mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        }
    }

    func checkLocationServices() {
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            setupLocationManager()
            checkLocationAuthorization()
        } else {

        }

    }

    func checkLocationAuthorization() {
        let pin = MKPointAnnotation()

        switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            mapView.showsUserLocation = true
            mapView.addAnnotation(pin)
            break
        case .denied:
            break
        case .notDetermined:
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            break
        case .restricted:
            break
        case .authorizedAlways:
            break
        }
    }

}

extension mapViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        // we'll be back
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        //we'll be back
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you put the required privacy item into the info.plist?

Comment: yes i did and still not showing up

Comment: Does it work on a real device? Are you prompted to give permission? Have you already denied permission and maybe need to change it in Privacy-Settings? Also have you checked the entire map (zoom out all the way) in case the default example location is somewhere else. The simulator won’t use your actual position unless you give it the real coordinate.

Comment: A minor point: The `mapView.showsUserLocation = true` is not in the right place. Right now you’re only hitting that line if it’s already authorized. The first time you run the app, that line won’t be called. Move it to `viewDidLoad` or just set that feature in IB. That having been said, the problem may well rest elsewhere (e.g. a bad `mapView(_:viewFor:)` implementation, if any).

Comment: Unrelated, as a matter of convention, class names should start with uppercase letter, e.g. `MapViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

Check Simulator menu: Features > Location > Custom Location

[image]